# Multiline TextBox that add new text always to the first line

Tags: c#, textbox, multiline

I'm asking for your help with something, that is a multiline that add text on the first line, instead of the above, like reversing.

When i click a button i want the text that is in a label to go to a multiline textbox, but in this case there are 3 multiline Texboxes:

i want a reverse result of this:

- text line 1
- text line 2
- text line 3

and have something like this:

- text line 3
- text line 2
- text line 1

But there like i said there is 3 multiline textbox, one for red numbers, one for zeros, and another for black numbers. This is for a roulette game, so when a random number is generated that number will go for one of the textbox (according to his color), and when i generate more numbers the old ones will be going down till there is no more text box left and then they disapear, and new ones will apear always on the first line.

So i have this code:

```
    static int[] preto = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 35 };
    static int[] vermelho = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36 };

    for (int l = 0; l < 18; l++)
            {
                if (lbl_random.Text == "0")
                {
                    txt_zeros.Text += lbl_random.Text + "\r\n";
                    txt_vermelhos.Text += "\r\n";
                    txt_pretos.Text += "\r\n";
                }

                else if (int.Parse(lbl_random.Text) == preto[l])
                {
                    txt_zeros.Text += "\r\n";
                    txt_pretos.Text += lbl_random.Text + "\r\n";
                    txt_vermelhos.Text += "\r\n";
                }
                else if (int.Parse(lbl_random.Text) == vermelho[l])
                {
                    txt_vermelhos.Text += lbl_random.Text + "\r\n";
                    txt_pretos.Text += "\r\n";
                    txt_zeros.Text += "\r\n";
                }
```

Comment: Why a TextBox (multiline or not)? This seems more adequate for a Listbox (you don't need to edit the text right?)

Comment: Is a multiline one, its a game, and what i want is something that tells me the previous numbers that came out, on the game, like a registry, if it is a roulette game, is to know what numbers have came out previously.

Comment: Do you mean this: `txt_pretos.Text = lbl_random.Text + "\r\n" + txt_pretos.Text;`?

Comment: Yes, but with a Listbox is more simple to insert an item in the top position of the list

Comment: @rene yes that worked l most as i want, being just left that on the other line would be given a new line as well and having something like this: 
http://i.imgur.com/gwIC0yJ.jpg
where there is 3 textbox, and at the left one there will be vermelho numbers, on the midlle one will be the zeros, and on the right the preto numbers

Comment: Instead of adding a line you clould simply replace the whole content of the TextBox, that's what I would do

Comment: @anhoppe and how do i do that? i have to insert like 10 new line in 3 diferent textbox, something like this
http://i.imgur.com/gwIC0yJ.jpg

Comment: @Steve I dont want to scroll and see what numbers have came out, this is a code for a roulette game, the intend is to have something like this: 
http://i.imgur.com/gwIC0yJ.jpg , 
and like on the imagens i will have 3 diferent colors and positions to the numbers that will be generated trought a new random number. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Multiline textbox try to use a Listbox for the three situations.
Notice that you should convert your label just one time and then use IndexOf (or Contains) on your arrays. No need to build a loop

```
static int[] preto = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 35 };
static int[] vermelho = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36 };

int number = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_random.Text);
if (number == 0)
{
   lstZeros.Items.Insert(0, "0");
   lstVermelhos.Items.Insert(0, "");
   lstPretos.Items.Insert(0, "");
}
else if (preto.Contains(number))
{
   lstZeros.Items.Insert(0, "");
   lstVermelhos.Items.Insert(0, "");
   lstPretos.Items.Insert(0, number.ToString());
}
else 
{
   // then is a black....
   lstZeros.Items.Insert(0, "");
   lstVermelhos.Items.Insert(0, number.ToString());
   lstPretos.Items.Insert(0, "");
}
```

In a Listbox all your numbers are stored in the Items collection and you could easily scroll and see the sequence of items inserted

Comment: I dont want to scroll and see what numbers have came out, this is a code for a roulette game, the intend is to have something like this: 
http://i.imgur.com/gwIC0yJ.jpg , 
and like on the imagens i will have 3 diferent colors and positions to the numbers that will be generated trought a new random number. thanks for your answer

Comment: And when all the lines of the TextBox are filled?  The scrolling is inevitable unless you delete the oldest numbers. With a Listbox you  Insert the last number at the first position (_Insert(0, number) So, the last number comes on top of the list items while the oldest are pushed out of sight. Sorry but I can't see your point.

Comment: what u told me worked but normaly there is no scroll to use, but that could be use full